# как создать переход по кругу картинок в слайдере на jquery, сейчас перелистывает из конца вначало

Tags: jquery, слайдер

```js
function Slider(width_li, margin_right_li, col_view_img) {
  var step = width_li + margin_right_li,
    slider_box_with = col_view_img * step - margin_right_li,
    $col_img = $(".slider_box>ul>li").length,
    col_main_left = 0,
    max_col_main_left = $col_img * step;
  $(".slider_box").width(slider_box_with);
  $(".slider_box>ul>li").width(width_li).css("margin-right", margin_right_li);
  $(".left_nav").click(function() {
    if (-col_main_left == max_col_main_left - col_view_img * step) {
      col_main_left = 0;
    } else {
      col_main_left = col_main_left - step;
    }
    $(".slider_box>ul").css("margin-left", col_main_left + "px");
  });
  $(".right_nav").click(function() {
    if (col_main_left == 0) {
      col_main_left = -max_col_main_left + col_view_img * step;
    } else {
      col_main_left = col_main_left + step;
    }
    $(".slider_box>ul").css("margin-left", col_main_left + "px");
  });
}
$(Slider(200, 5, 4));
```

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 815px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider_box {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider_box>ul>li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
}

.slider_box>ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1000%;
}

.nav_slider>div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
}

.nav_slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -130px;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.left_nav {
  float: left;
}

.right_nav {
  float: right;
}

.img_1 {
  background: #C3086C;
}

.img_2 {
  background-color: #26A7DE;
}

.img_3 {
  background-color: #E97912;
}

.img_4 {
  background-color: #6EBE65;
}

.img_5 {
  background-color: #FF2A2A;
}

.img_6 {
  background-color: #7C59EC;
}

.img_7 {
  background-color: #FF7700;
}

.img_8 {
  background-color: #0393D7;
}

.img_9 {
  background-color: #BD1D20;
}

.img_10 {
  background-color: #eeef25;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider_box">
    <ul>
      <li class="img_1">1</li>
      <li class="img_2">2</li>
      <li class="img_3">3</li>
      <li class="img_4">4</li>
      <li class="img_5">5</li>
      <li class="img_6">6</li>
      <li class="img_7">7</li>
      <li class="img_8">8</li>
      <li class="img_9">9</li>
      <li class="img_10">10</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="nav_slider">
    <div class="left_nav"></div>
    <div class="right_nav"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно поставить условие, чтобы на последнем шаге, когда Ваши картинки доходят до конца, обнулять значение и начинать сначала.

Comment: я понимаю что надо использовать .appendTo()  .prependTo() но как правильно прописать чтоб работало корректно не могу(

Comment: Почему вы написали это как ответ? Это должен быть комментарий.